# css button with arrow... how to move arrow

Tags: css, css-shapes

I am trying to make a basic button box with an arrow at the top of it...

http://jsfiddle.net/8K4qB/  --this is what it comes out to.. i can't make it align at the top in the middle of the bottom.

### HTML Code

```html
 <a href="" class="button test">Read More</a>
```

### CSS Code

```css
.button {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
    padding:10px 30px 10px 30px;
    margin:0 auto;
      background: #2ecc71;

}

    .test:before {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: 20px solid #3498db;
    border-right:50px solid transparent;
    border-left:50px solid transparent;
        }
```

[image: want I want it to look like]

I'd like it to look like the pic

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8K4qB/4/

Comment: Just to point out: It's all about the top and left (or bottom and right respectively) attributes when using an absolute position.

Comment: that is right of course.. to adjust a position.. but lets assume your are using a div with 100% and make the arrow set at 50% left you will get it probably in the middle right?

Comment: Yes that is right, but with an evenly shaped arrow (like your 50px left and right border) these 50px will be added.
Like @Charaf jra 's example leaving the left (and right) value empty it gets centered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to achieve the specific behaviour you're after you need to change your HTML as well as your CSS- otherwise centrally justifying a pseudo element correctly will elude you.. Change the elements in the example as required (e.g. the top level `div` can be changed to `a.button.test`)

## [**REVISED FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8K4qB/9/)

HTML

```
<div>
    <div></div>
    <div>text goes here</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
}
div div:first-child {
    display:block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: 10px solid darkorange;
    border-right:30px solid transparent;
    border-left:30px solid transparent;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
div div:last-child{
    display:block;
   font-size: 15px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding:10px 30px 10px 30px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background: darkorange;
    position:relative;
    text-transform:uppercase; 
}
```

Comment: but using this doesn't accurately move the arrow to the center...

meanwhile that if i change the dimensions of the arrow not to be as wide it will not shift properly.

i figured that much using pixels, but it is not a viable solution if dimensions are changed

Answer (score 1):

Try this ,display:block so that your arrow still in the middle:  [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/SG47X/)

CSS:

```
.button {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
    padding:10px 30px 10px 30px;
    margin:0 auto;
      background: #2ecc71;
     display:block;position:relative;top:20px;
 }
.test:before {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top:-20px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: 20px solid #3498db;
    border-right:50px solid transparent;
    border-left:50px solid transparent;
        }
.middle{
    padding-left:15px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="" class="button test"><span class="middle">Read More</span></a>
```

Comment: is the read more in the middle or are my eyes playing tricks on me .. it is 4am here